# Yarn Workspaces, workspace does not emit errors or warnings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I have followed the following [post](https://medium.com/frontend-digest/using-create-react-app-in-a-monorepo-a4e6f25be7aa) in order to create a monorepo using yarn workspaces and craco.
It works really well except one thing: the  errors/warnings of the common (components )library are not emitted to the console.
The structure is very simple:

```
monorepo
|-packages
  |-components
  |-fe
```

Fe is the main webApp that uses the components library.
The FE emits all warnings correctly, components does not.

How to make the shared component emit warnings/errors?

***Updated:***

Steps to reproduce in this repo:
https://github.com/sofoklisM/my-monorepo.git

Comment: Can you share exactly what has happened? Also share a reproducible repo?

Comment: Repo added. The link to the post also contains all details. The *shared* library 'components' does not emit any warnings/errors after compiling. If for example a warning or error is introduced in Button.js, i will see in gitbash console it is compiling, and then I will get the message 'Compiled successfully'. No warnings, no errors.

Comment: What did you run to expect having an error occurred in component?

Comment: pls see in repo the following unused imports : packages/components/src/Button.js : (useEffect, useCallback). Or try using an undeclared variable. No errors again, Try the same thing in FE, warnings/ errors emitted.

Comment: Ah I see. I don't think it's doable that way. Why don't you set up a eslint for each package which extends from root repo then run it before running start.

Comment: Ok, I installed eslint in components workspace and added in scripts of package.json     "eslint": "^7.16.0".  If I run yarn run eslint "./**/*.js" I get all the warnings/errors of the workspace. I haven't managed to make it run automatically everytime the project compiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to change is the [`context` option](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-webpack-plugin#context) of the [underlying ESLint Webpack plugin](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L753) that is used by Create React App.
In this case I changed the context of ESLint to the root of the monorepo (yarn workspace root).

Here is an updated `craco.config.js` that should do the trick:

```
// craco.config.js
const path = require("path");
const { getLoader, loaderByName } = require("@craco/craco");
const { getPlugin, pluginByName } = require("@craco/craco/lib/webpack-plugins")
const absolutePath = path.join(__dirname, "../components");
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    alias: {},
    plugins: [],
    configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => {
      const { isFound, match } = getLoader(
        webpackConfig,
        loaderByName("babel-loader")
      );
      if (isFound) {
        const include = Array.isArray(match.loader.include)
          ? match.loader.include
          : [match.loader.include];
        match.loader.include = include.concat([absolutePath]);
      }

      // Change context of ESLint Webpack Plugin
      const { match: eslintPlugin } = getPlugin(webpackConfig, pluginByName("ESLintWebpackPlugin"));
      eslintPlugin.options['context'] = path.join(__dirname, "../..");

      return webpackConfig;
    }
  }
};
```

I've also made an updated fork of your reproduction repo here: https://github.com/ofhouse/stackoverflow-65447779

Comment: For some reason if I use error boundaries I get an error: Failed to load config "./node_modules/kcd-scripts/eslint.js" to extend from.
Referenced from: ...my-monorepo\node_modules\react-error-boundary\package.json, The entire App was inside an ErrorBoundary, it worked when I removed it.

Comment: Okay this sounds like eslint tries to lint code in the `node_modules/react-error-boundary` package for some reason. I have an idea what happened here, will try to reproduce that error later today.

Comment: Ok had a typo in code instead of `path.join(__dirname, "../../")` we had to use `path.join(__dirname, "../..")` (without tailing `/`). Should work now, I have updated the answer and the fork as well.